# Using a LDAP proxy to debug LDAP requests

Tags: linux, proxy, active-directory, ldap

I currently fail to configure an application using LDAP/ActiveDirectory properly. The application - from my point of view - is a black box. Therefore, I cannot see what goes wrong with the LDAP requests...

My idea now is to use a proxy for the LDAP requests. This proxy should do nothing more than receive the requests, write them to a logfile, and then send them to the (external) LDAP server.

What tools would one use to realize such a simple man-in-the-middle for LDAP on Linux/Debian?

Answer (score 2):

My usual approach would be slightly different: the best is to inspect requests and responses with Wireshark (based on a tcpdump captured pcap file if you need to trace on a remote system). This way you see the precise error, the LDAP filters used, the base DN etc, i.e. this way you can be quite sure to identify the source of the issue.

Now you might face an issue with SSL: your server side might enforce TLS. In this case you can put some `stunnel` instance in between - you access the tunnel end by plain LDAP, the `stunnel` "proxy" wraps it into TLS (resulting in LDAPS of course).