# LDAP proxy (or pass-through) to another LDAP server

Tags: proxy, ldap

This is probably somewhat similar to [Using a LDAP proxy to debug LDAP requests](https://superuser.com/questions/1569475/using-a-ldap-proxy-to-debug-ldap-requests) but the answer there is not really helpful.

I need to connect multiple services which run in a Docker swarm to an external LDAP server, which has a lot of restrictions regarding the access. The procedure to "enroll" an LDAP client requires a password authentication and generates a token which is bound to the IP of the client (and checked via reverse-look-up on each LDAP request).

This makes is very difficult to automatically set it up for dozens of services in a Docker swarm or Kubernetes network.

One obvious solution is to manually set up a single server and use that as a "proxy LDAP" by forwarding all the LDAP requests from the services to the external LDAP provider.

Is there a recommended approach? I have found some LDAP proxy solutions (based on OpenLDAP) but those are meant to proxy an Active Directory server. All I need is a bridge to another LDAP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLDAP is designed to be able to proxy to any generic LDAP server. While the specific tutorials you've found might have AD-specific configuration, that is not really the case for the software itself (and AD behaves 98% like a standard LDAP server anyway).

The `ldap` database backend should work here, if you need to program some fixed credentials.

In addition, the latest OpenLDAP branch (2.6) has the `lloadd` daemon as a *dedicated* LDAP proxy and load-balancer.

Comment: Yes, many thanks. I realised it after I raised my question and went deeper into the docs. I'll try it out :)